# Windows doesn't show up in grub2 can't access BIOS or boot with CD

Tags: grub2, bios

I installed Ubuntu yesterday I had 3 partitions:

- `c:/` Windows
- `d:/` other files
- `w:/` linux mint

when installing Ubuntu I chose 'replace linux mint'

problem:

After rebooting Windows didn't show up in Grub menu.
I've tried Grub update but it only detected Ubuntu (only 2 partitions).
I've tried booting with CD but it goes directly To Grub2.
I've tried accessing BIOS but it said 'please wait..' than directly goes to Grub2.

I think I made a mistake, I've tried to remove Ubuntu partition with Gparted (I was desperate) now I can't even open Ubuntu.
please help me I don't want to loose my files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have become a victim of one of the the most severe bugs in Ubuntu:

The "Replace «some OS»" option actually purges the **whole** disk. So you just reformatted your whole HDD instead of the LM partition. There has been an open bug report on Launchpad for about a year,but there is now fix yet.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1265192

Have fun recovering all the data you need: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: Please, could you suggest me a solution for recovering the system, I can't boot with CD nor Ubunto now (after arazing ubunto partition with gparted).

Comment: To enable boot from CD, change the boot order in your BIOS

Comment: I can't access my BIOS anymore, its says 'please wait' and then goes to Grub2 ' which has only ubunto listed and if I select it it stucks at loading. and when I chose recovery mode it's says no physical data and stucks there.

Comment: Then use GRUB2's command line (hotkey c) to manually boot from the CD

Comment: could you give me which commands do I have to use to do so. I'm stuck.

Comment: What does the command `ls` return?

Comment: (hd0) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (cd0)

Comment: `set root=(cd0)` `linux /vmlinuz* root=/dev/sdb1 ro` `initrd /initrd.img` `boot`. If this doesn't work, I can't help you any further...

Comment: thank you @the_Seppi. it says /vmlinuz* not found :(

Comment: What about `/boot/vmlinuz*`? Or instead of the asterisk, use the TAB key for autocomplete